# Where can i get documentation for .doc file format

Tags: c++, file-format

I have written a program that currently can only read and write to openformat types, but this is not convnient to some users, what doccumentation can i purchase for .doc , .docx, etx... thank you.

Comment: What about using Apache POI instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: The [official file format specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105%28v=office.12%29.aspx) can be found at MSDN. It's probably too complex to write a reasonable implementation on your own though (for .doc it's ~600 pages of specs).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to purchase anything. Don't try to reinvent the wheel instead use some library avaiable on the net like [`docx4j`](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j), or the `Apache POI` like Thomas and piet.t suggested.

For the record, I never used this library. But their website seems very complete and the forum section is active and filled with a lot of posts. Also I've already heard people talking about it (but I guess it's just hear say so it doesn't count) So it seems to be a good one.

One little quote found on their website :

> "congratulations for the great job, I can do things that I cannot with POI or OpenOffice? API !!"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the whell just take a look a the [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org) library. That one will allow you to create or manipulate dox or docx documents via java-API.

Comment: LaurentG beat me by 22 secs....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), which should at least be able to read .doc files.

Here's some info on POI's .doc and .docx support: http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html